# Como criar um componete que traga dados de 2 url's via fecth api?

Tags: react

tenho 2 endereços de API abaixo, e preciso criar um card em react que traga a foto da primeira API, e o post da segunda.

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/ 
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then(response=> response.json())
  .then(users => {this.setState({ post: users})});
}
render() {
    const { post, searchfield } = this.state;
    const filteredPost = post.filter(post =>{
        return post.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchfield.toLowerCase());
})
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1 style={{ textAlign: 'center'}}>
                Busca de Posts
            </h1>
            <Buscador searchChange={this.onSearchChange} />
            <div className='wrapper'>
                <UserList post={filteredPost} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Faz duas requisições e uni os resultados, qual é o problema?

Comment: não sei como unir os resultados...

estaria certa essa forma?

let Apidois = ['https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts']

componentDidMount() {
  fetch Apidois
  .then(response=> response.json())
  .then(users => {this.setState({ post: users})});
}

Comment: Precisa analisar as APIs e ver que dados as duas tem em comum para usar na união